# Sorteio com probabilidade com array

Tags: php

Olá, boa noite
Estou tentando fazer um sorteio com probabilidades em cada item, estou organizando cada item do sorteio em uma array, exemplo:

```
$premios = [
'Iphone 8' =>      0.5,
'Kit Maquiagem' => 10,
'Botas de Couro' => 25,
'Fone' => 35,
'Teclado Gamer' => 40,
'Capinha' => 50,
];
```

e estou tratando da seguinte maneira

```
$x = rand(0, 100);
foreach ($premios as $premio => $probability) {
$x -= $probability;
if ($x <= 0) {
echo $premio;
break;
}
}
```

Mas não está me retornando resultados sastifatorios.
Alguém pode da ideia de como melhora este código?

Comment: e a soma dessas probabilidades ai passando de 100?

Comment: @vmp ajuda ai d=